# Порядок подключения скриптов в webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

структура такая

```
app.js  
-lib.js   
-common.js
```

```js
    app.js
    import './js/lib.js';
    import './js/common.js';
```

в lib описана какая-то функция, в common она используется, но в полученном файле получается так, что функция используется до описания функции и я получаю **rightLine is not defined**. Как мне сделать так, чтобы соблюдалась очередность?

Но что еще непонятно, почему даже если в бандле она описана после, она не вызывается, ведь она все равно должна быть видна уже.

[image: output]

Comment: На Вашем скрине видно, что функция `rightLine()` не находится в области видимости модуля `common.js`. Импорт должен выглядеть несколько по другому.

Comment: Почему у Вас так произошло - [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0). Простейший рабочий [пример](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fcygw5?file=index.js).

Comment: Услышал, буду читать и разбираться, спасибо